Hyper-V VHDX keeps growing in file size for 12 hours non-stop & unstoppable after deleting VM
I was using Hyper-V. I attempted to remove a VM in Hyper-V, I was expecting to be able to remove the VHDX and the checkpoint files immediately afterwards, but the VHDX automatically goes into merging process & cannot be removed & keeps growing in file size for 12 hours non-stop.




In contrary to the expected result, the actual situation is -

the VHDX file keeps growing in size
the VHDX file and its corresponding checkpoint files are locked by SYSTEM PID: 4
checked inside Windows Event Log to find out that the VHD is being performed merge.
the VHDX file originally was just 180 GB & the checkpoints accumulatively are just < 500 GB big.
after waiting for more than 12 hours, the VHDX file becomes 1693 GB & still growing in a rate of 100 GB / hour.
this particular thing is making the server perform slower by 20x.


I wonder if:

I ever hit a bug in Hyper-V?
Is the merging expected to create very big HD file out of thin air?
Assuming these VHDX files are free to dispose of, am I able to run net stop vmms and net start vmms to unlock the merging files & make the server healthy again - without ever killing any of the other of my 20 Hyper-V VMs' processes?


